# Chart.js: load new data on click

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have multiple data sets and want to change when a button is clicked. Here is an example of what I need: http://codepen.io/marcelo2605/pen/JEoGEO?editors=1010

If I click on 'set 2' button, the chart load the correct data.

But when I try to load 'set 1', nothing happens.

When I inspect using `console.log`, I saw that `foo` variable value is the same for both buttons.

Comment: looks like it's just eval misbehaving, why not place all data into one object, broken into 2 instead of running eval on variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this :

```
myChart.data.datasets[0] = foo['datasets'][0];
myChart.data.labels = foo['labels'];
myChart.update();
```

To this :

```
myChart.config.data  = foo;
myChart.update();
```

Edit after comments :

[link to latest state](http://codepen.io/osmanraifgunes/pen/vgEdYw)

Comment: I think it works, but without animation. Is possible to run animation every time new data load?

Comment: So you should use myChart.destroy(); and then recreate it.

Comment: A quick way to get the full animation is simply replace the full table each time instead of updating the data attributes. `update()` is likely intended for streaming data.

Comment: @alttag Could you show an example of how can I do that?

Comment: Wrap `myChart = new Chart( ... )` in a function. Call the function when you get new data.

Comment: @alttag OK. But this way a new iframe is created, keeping the old one.

Comment: Put myChart.destroy() before create.

Comment: @osmanraifgunes Not working. Return myChart.destroy is not a function: http://codepen.io/marcelo2605/pen/egmyMv?editors=0010